# When subclassing "double" with new properties in MATLAB, is there an easy way to access the data value?

Tags: matlab, indexing, double, variable-assignment, subclass

Say I have a class subclassing double, and I want to add a string (Similar to the 'extendDouble' in the documentation). Is there an easy way to access the actual numeric value without the extra properties, particular for reassigning? Or if I want to change the value, will I have to recreate the value as a new member of the class with the new value and the same string?

e.g.

```
classdef myDouble < double

properties
    string
end

methods 
    function obj = myDouble(s)
        % Construct object (simplified)
        obj.string = s;
    end
end

end

----------

x = myDouble(2,'string')
x = 
    2 string
    
x = 3
x = 
    3 string
```

Comment: Can you show your class definition? I don't know the examples in the documentation by heart... :)

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to reassign the numeric value in the simple way you would like. When you execute `x=3`, you are asking MATLAB to _generate_ a new variable `x` (destroying whatever `x` was if it existed before) and assign it the `double` value `3`. With that syntax, there is no way an already existing variable `x` could intercept the high level MATLAB assignment and decide to send the command to be parsed by its own `subasgn/subsref`.

Comment: I am affraid you need the dot assignment to trigger that recognition. You would need to execute `x.Data=3` which is what you are trying to avoid, but unfortunately I think the best you can do is change the `Data` and `DataString` field names to something shorter (like `v` for _value_ and `s` for _string_).

Comment: Hoki, there currently is no data field for this as it derives from the double class, and it seems the value is stored inherently. Having to track the value as a property would defeat the whole point of subclassing double, no?

Comment: @ robbie crockett You really need to show us the code for this class as Cris Luengo has already requested. Then we can show you how the double and string data are stored in the class and how to manipulate them. You seem to be under the mistaken impression that an assignment in MATLAB such as x=3 will somehow retain the class that x was before the assignment ... it won't.

Comment: As my edit shows, the myDouble class is a subclass of double, so it should inherit certain properties, such as the actual double value. But, I don't know if there's a way to access the actual value that is stored so that it can be reassigned while retaining the string data. I'd like to avoid recreating the object as a new myDouble if possible.

Comment: I would suggest cross posting this on Mathworks Answers where some OOP experts can chime in on your code design.

Comment: If you are following the code [on this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/built-in-subclasses-with-properties.html), then you need to do `x.Data = 3`. That class has explicitly overloaded the `subsref` and `subsasgn` methods so you can do that. That code defines a fake `Data` field. It then creates a new object with the new value and the old string, and returns that. So I guess you can’t change the value without creating a new object. Is there a specific reason you don’t want to create a new object? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I honestly don’t see the use of subclassing `double`. Using the subclass in an arithmetic expression, for example, will automatically cast it back to `double` unless you overload the arithmetic operator for your class. If you’re going to do that, you might as well create a new numeric class from scratch.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Yes I also fail to see a good use for these contraptions. It seems Mathworks gives you an example to show it can be done but are not really recommending it. From the example: "`When a subclass of a built-in class defines properties, default indexing and concatenation do not work. The default subsref, subsasgn, horzcat, and vertcat functions cannot work with unknown property types and values. Therefore, the subclass must define these behaviors by implementing these methods.`". It's a lot of work for limited functionalities.

Comment: A simple class with 2 properties (a `double` and a `string`) would offer a container with the same functionalities and a lot less work to set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: NO. There is no *easy* way to access a single member of a class when the class contains more than one member. You'll always have to let MATLAB know which part of the class you want to manipulate.

You have multiple questions in your post but let's tackle the most interesting one first:

```
% you'd like to instanciate a new class this way (fine)
x = myDouble(2,'string')
x = 
    2 string
% then you'd like to easily refer to the only numeric part of your class
% for assignment => This can NEVER work in MATLAB.
x = 3
x = 
    3 string
```

This can never work in MATLAB because of how the interpreter works. Consider the following statements:

```
% direct assignment
(1) dummy = 3
% indexed assignments
(2) dummy(1) = 3
(3) dummy{1} = 3
(4) dummy.somefieldname = 3
```

You would like the simplicity of the first statement for assignment, but this is the one we cannot achieve. The statement 2, 3 and 4 are all possible with some fiddling with `subasgn` and `subsref`.

The main difference between (1) and [2,3,4] is this:

**Direct assignment:**

In MATLAB, when you execute a direct assignment to a simple variable name (without indexing with `()` or `{}` or a field name) like `dummy=3`, MATLAB does not check the type of `dummy` beforehand, in fact it does not even check whether the variable `dummy` exists at all. No, with this kind of assignment, MATLAB goes the quickest way, it immediately *create* a new variable `dummy` and assign it the type and value accordingly. If a variable `dummy` existed before, too bad for it, that one is lost forever (and a lot of MATLAB users have had their fingers bitten once or twice by this behavior actually as it is an easy mistake to overwrite a variable and MATLAB will not raise any warning or complaint)

**Indexed assignments:**

In all the other cases, something different happens. When you execute `dummy(1)=3`, you are not telling MATLAB "create a new `dummy` variable with that value", you are telling MATLAB, "find the existing `dummy` variable, find the existing subindex I am telling you, then assign the value to that specific subindex". MATLAB will happlily go on, if it finds everything it does the sub-assignment, or it might complains/error about any kind of misassignment (wrong index, type mismatch, indices length mismatch...).

To find the subindex, MATLAB will call the `subassgn` method of `dummy`. If `dummy` is a built-in class, the `subassgn` method is also built in and usually under the hood, if `dummy` is a custom class, then you can write your own `subassgn` and have full control on how MATLAB will treat the assignment. You can check for the type of the input and decide to apply to this field or another if it's more suitable. You can even do some range check and reject the assignment altogether if it is not suitable, or just assign a default value. You have full control, MATLAB will not force you to anything in your own `subassgn`.

The problem is, to trigger MATLAB to relinquish control and give the hand to your own `subassgn`, you have to use an indexed assignment (like [2,3 or 4] above). You cannot do that with type (1) assignment.

---

Other considerations: You also ask if you can change the numeric part of the class without creating a new object. The answer to that is no as well. This is because of the way value classes work in matlab. There could be a long explanation of what happens under the hood, but the best example is from the MATLAB example you referenced yourself. If we look at the class definition of [ExtendDouble](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/built-in-subclasses-with-properties.html), then observe the custom `subassgn` method which will perform the change of numeric value, what happens there is:

```
obj = ExtendDouble(b,obj.DataString);
```

So even Mathworks, to change the numeric value of their extended double class, have to recreate a brand new one (with a new numeric value `b`, and transfering the old string value `obj.DataString`).

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much the conclusion I've come to. The reason I'm trying to do this is to see if I could increase the speed of assignment, since there's a tiny slowdown when creating a new variable that compounds quickly in a loop.

Comment: If your concern is about speed in loops then best to avoid custom classes if possible. Loops will always be significantly faster on MATLAB built in types. Do you really need a label string attached on every element you handle? May be you could just maintain a separate array of labels/strings.